# Is putItem() an async function? If yes, then why does my Lambda function timeout with just ~20 putItem() calls?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a function, which fetches some data from an API and writes it to a DynamoDB database. The API request and data processing takes about 1.5 sec. With my test set of data I have to put no more than 20 items in the database and the Lambda used to timeout before I raised the maximum execution time.

I tried to write only the first item to the database and the execution time increase was minimal. This makes me think that putItem() is a synchronous function. Is there a way to just send those write requests and not wait for an answer from the database? Or can I make them async?

This is how I'm calling putItem() for each item:

```
items.forEach(item => {
  let params = {
    TableName: '..'
    Item: { .. }
  }
  
  db.putItem(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      log(err)
    }
    log('Inserted property.')
  })
})
```

Can I optimize this process so it doesn't take that long?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it's not a synchronous function, as it has callback. But even for async functions, the aws lambda function will of course run until all async callbacks are finished, ie the execution stack is empty ...

Comment: @derpirscher So DynamoDB queues up actions then?

Comment: In your case you make a bunch of parallel requests. I don't know how dynamoDB handles them, but the lambda function for sure will run until all of them are finished, either with an error or success ...

Comment: @derpirscher If you have a suggestion how to optimise this feel free to post it as an answer, that my question

Comment: I really don't have a suggestion for you, sorry. For that, I'd have to know more about your project and also DynamoDB (which I personally have never worked with). Just pointed out, why the lambda function also may run into a timeout with async functions.

Comment: You could consider using batching to reduce the number of individual connections, should be a lot faster - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write-batch.html#dynamodb-example-table-read-write-batch-writing)

Comment: Dos your lambda also time out with just one item? What about 2 or 3? As other have pointed out `putItem` is actually an async function and contrary to what others have stated, a Lambda function will not actually wait for the putItem requests to complete before returning, unless you specifically wait for the results -- in fact, without waiting, lambda might terminate your function even before completing the pending puts resulting in data loss.. something about your usecase doesn't add up

Comment: @MikeDinescu I just have an array, I loop over the array and call putItem() for each item. The lambda doesn't time out with just 2 or 3 putItem() calls.